# Efficient local storage and access of maps in a mobile app?

Tags: java, data-structures, java-me, maps, processing-efficiency

What is the efficient way (with respect to memory and speed) to store and access maps for a mobile app? Don't want to use internet streaming for the maps.

Are the following ways efficient?

- Store the maps as images in the mobile's local memory
- Access the images by its file paths all stored in an array
- Also each map has 2 opposite corner coordinates stored in a text file which is accessed to apply a coordinate system for the map.
- The coordinates from the text file are read/parsed with input stream and stored in arrays (ie. an array for x and y).

So the above ways have 2 types of files: an image and a text file with 2 coordinates (for each image). And arrays for map paths and corner coordinates. I understand I would use file connection (persistent storage).

**In the end, would like to:** 
Develop a mobile app that can view maps locally and change maps according to user's coordinate cursor. I guess the map change can occur with boundary checking the specified coordinates with user's coordinate cursor. For example call a changeMap(x, y) in a paint(...) method.

So please suggest a cleaner and efficient way to store and access maps with coordinates.

Comment: "Also each map has 2 opposite corner coordinates stored in a text file which is accessed to apply a coordinate system for the map" - instead of this, you can use only ONE text file for all maps and store data as "mapID" "x-co ordinate" "y-coordinate"... this way you will prevent searching and loading of a text file each time you change the map..

Comment: Ok having one text file with all the map's coordinates makes sense. But the text files are parsed once and their coordinates stored in an array. So the coordinates in the array are linearly checked in this array before changing the map. The size of this array is same as size of the array with map file paths. So with the array there is one-to-one mapping with map file and corner coordinates.

Comment: I guess it would be more efficient to read/parse a single text file with all maps coordinates once. But to store these coordinates in app memory would it be efficient to use 4 one-D arrays to store the coordinates, ie. for top left x and y and bottom right x and y?

Comment: why do u need bottom x and y positions??... your top x and y are enough right?

Comment: No, will need bottom right and top left positions to know boundary/limit of map. How can I attract more responses for my question?

Answer (score 0):

why not combine multiple methods? If text data isn't too heavy, you can store it in RMS. You can store images in RMS too, newer devices do not have theoretical limits on size of RMS, however a record store cannot exceed about 500KB. Store larger files on the memory card.

Comment: Ok not a bad idea. I need the text data is to be linked with an image. So how to do this with RMS?

Comment: Also what is a way to test or practically measure the size (resolution/file size) of an image a phone can handle within a J2ME application?

Comment: The best guideline is that most j2me phones have 2MB heap for java apps, your app cannot exceed this heap else it would throw an outofmemory exception. You need to work with your apps within this limit, i suggest that a 500KB image should not be much of a problem, provided your application is not already eating up too much memory. 1MB image would be pushing it but still possible. A 2MB image would only work on phones with 4MB heap. Profile your app to see the memory usage, but i think 500KB should work.

Comment: What is the size of  your text data and image? You should be able to use separate record stores to store the image and also text seperately with a common ID to allow you identify them. If the data is not large, then you could save both data in a record store. Also please have a look at the Tantalum Library https://github.com/TantalumMobile/Tantalum it has a lot of functions that may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Text data for each map is <1KB. Image size can be between 200 - 500KB. I will just use file connection API instead of RMS. I have read that for anything past a few kilobytes need to use either file connection rather than RMS. I will do some profiling to see if max 500KB image size is acceptable by the app.

Comment: If I have multiple text files then all those files total size (e.g. ~270KB) is lower than having a single text file with all the data (e.g. ~400KB). I'm wondering if it is efficient to read/parse a multiple text files once or a single text file once. I thought it is CPU and resource intensive to run the file parser/reader multiple times, but having multiple text files results in less space. So I'm not sure how to decide on the trade off...

Comment: I think with multiple files, you do not have to sort the data, just call each file when you need it. If it is all in one file, you will have to loop through to find what you are looking for, which will be a performance hit. I reckon you do not use all the text files at once, the parser/reader is only called when needed, as opposed to running it once with one file but keeping unnecessary data on hand, just cause you don't want to re-run the parser.